# How to implement resiliency (retry) in a nested service call chain

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure, rest, microservices, envoyproxy

We have a webpage that queries an item from an API gateway which in turn calls a service that calls another service and so on.

Webpage --> API Gateway --> service#1 --> service#2 --> data store (RDMS, S3, Azure blob)

We want to make the operation resilient so we added a retry mechanism at every layer.

Webpage --*retry*--> API Gateway --*retry*--> service#1 --*retry*--> service#2 --*retry*--> data store.

This however could case a [cascading failure](https://sre.google/sre-book/addressing-cascading-failures/) because if the data store doesn't response on time, it will cause every layer to timeout and retry. In other words, if each layer has the same connection timeout and is configured to retry 3 times, then there will be a total of 81 retries to the data store (which is called a retry storm).

One way to fix this is to increase the timeout at each layer in order to give the layer below time to retry.

Webpage --*5m timeout*--> API Gateway --*2m timeout*--> service#1

This however is unacceptable because the timeout at the webpage will be too long.

How should I address this problem?

Should there only be one layer that retries? Which layer? And how can the layer know if the error is transient?

Comment: 1) do you use any messaging system here?  2) Why retry at every step, just place the retry mechanism at the persistence layer because if any failure happens before the persistence layer then just return the failure response to a client so there will consistency. If call reached to persistence layer then add a retry mechanism. If still getting failure after retry, then return error response.

Comment: 1) We don't use any messaging system and we can't. 2) We retry at every step because a failure can happen at any point. The chances of persistence layer failing is no higher that the other parts of the system. Obviously, our current implement is not perfect which is why I posted this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple possible solutions (and you can/should use both) would be to retry on different conditions and implement rate limiters/circuit breakers.

Retry On is a technique where you don't retry on every condition, but only specific conditions.  This could be a specific error code or a specific header value.  E.g. in your current situation, DO NOT retry on timeouts; only retry on server failures.  In addition, you could have each layer retry on different conditions

Rate limiting would be to stick either a local or global rate limiter service inline to the connections.  This would just help to short-circuit the thundering herd in the case that it starts up.  E.g. rate limit the data layer to X req/s (insert real values here) and the gateway to Y req/s and then even if a service attempts lots of retries it won't pass too far down the chain.  Similarly to this is circuit breaking, where each layer only permits X active connections to any downstream, so just another way to slow those retry storms.

Comment: My impression is retrying on timeout is a standard practice for microservices. Is it not?

Comment: in my experience retry on timeout is fairly common as a first step, but quickly runs into just the problem you describe.  The issue is that if something takes longer than expected, that likely means the server is already in distress.  Retrying shortly is just going to further burden it.  Proxys like [envoy](https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/latest/api-v3/config/route/v3/route_components.proto#config-route-v3-retrypolicy) don't set a default, but ask the user to select what they want to retry on so that it's made with some knowledge.

Comment: Thanks for your help. So you don't retry at all on timeout? We retry after a delay but our problem the retry wait will cause the downstream services to timeout.

Do you modify your upstream services to not retry and instead return an HTTP status code that tells the downstream service to initiate a retry?

Comment: Yeah, basically.  What's best is for the services to respond with codes and/or headers that indicate what to do, and the retry policy to respect that.  E.g. a 404 should probably never be retried: if it's not found once, checking again is unlikely to help.  Similarly with 403 forbidden and tons more codes.  If you do need to retry on a timeout somewhere (bad network connection or something) just keep it to the layer that you know hits that issue and not the whole stack.  And make sure its on a service that is idempotent, or the retry could cause something to happen more times than desired